# Alamorefire(Swift 3) : Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(..'

Tags: ios, file-upload, swift3, alamofire

I use `Alamorefire` for `Swift 3` but got the error:`Ambiguous reference to member 'upload`.
Here is my code:

```
Alamofire.upload(
    .post,
    url,
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        // import parameters
        for i in 0 ..< params.count {
            for (key, value) in params[i] {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                                                 name: key)
            }
        }
        // import image to request
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData,
                                         name: "file",
                                         fileName: "file.jpg",
                                         mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    },
    encodingMemoryThreshold: SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response.result)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: kindly response to my answer.

Comment: I had the same issue. My problem was that I was trying to pass a `[String : String]` dictionary for the “headers” parameter. I solved the problem by explicitly converting the dictionary to an `HTTPHeaders` by writing `HTTPHeaders(myDictionary)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below code

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoImageView.image!, 0.5)!, withName: "photo_path", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
    }
    }, to:"http://server1/upload_img.php")
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
            //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
            //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
        print(encodingError)
    }

}
```

Comment: This answer presents a completely different piece of code than was in the question, and it does not explain what was actually wrong with the original code.